# Panel Transparency in KDE Plasma

Tags: kubuntu, kde, themes, panel, plasma-5

Okay, So using Kubuntu/KDE Plasma 5.13, I can obviously change colors, add panels and do a lot of personalization stuff that I really like. But what I am really interested in is changing the transparency/translucency of the panel. I can't do it via settings/(any other GUI stuff) obviously. Is there any kind of tweak (editing configuration files, etc.), coz I know it's possible as they create translucent/transparent themes. How is this done?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, you cannot edit any config file to do so, but rather have to change the background image of the panel to something that is transparent (i.e. an SVG file that is transparent)

Comment: I can use Illustrator to do it. Where does the file reside?

Comment: https://github.com/psifidotos/plasma-transparent-panel This is a github project that actually looks like it creates panel transparency through a python script. This (in hindsight) might actually prove more useful to you!

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I may have to disable some things, but I will give it a shot!

Comment: Hi, it's possible by setting the appropriate opacity via *Window Management > Window Rules > New > Window Type > Panel (dock)* and then clicking on the *Appearance and Fixes* tab and setting your Active opacity/Inactive opacity.

Answer (score 1):

**Breeze AlphaBlack**

AlphaBlack Control - https://store.kde.org/p/1237963/

> A simple widget to control the desktop theme's accent color, panel
>   opacity, and the style of the taskbar's window buttons.
>   Requires: Breeze AlphaBlack v10+ (https://store.kde.org/p/1084931/)

Comment: Wow, that's cool. Will try it for sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Update: there is a transparency panel button widget that is available under "Get new widgets" option.

Once added, select "Edit Panel", then close the main options

[image]

Then use the button

[image]